# How to cut string on last underscore character?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, ls, command

I have list of files like below:

```
[root@ods1 backup]# ls -l
total 93892810
-rw-r----- 1 root root 651248 Feb 17 08:34  abc_def_g_17-02-2022.sql
-rw------- 1 root root 665248 Mar 23 08:46  bbc_23-03-2022.sql
-rw-r----- 1 root root 676992 Apr 04 16:52  zz_b_04-04-2022.sql
```

What i need to achieve is:

```
abc_def_g
bbc
zz_b
```

I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d '_' -f1-2
```

How can I achieve this goal? Any series of commands that get the lines until last **_** character should do the job.

Edit: This commands are executed in CentOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
ls|awk -F_ '{NF-=1}1' OFS=_
```

Here the trick is to decrease number of fields by one (strip the last fiels)

Comment: Many thanks, it worked.

Comment: If you just need to obtain a list to read for humans and/or you control the input files, that option is fine. But files are allowed to have a `\n` included, so it might break in a script when you cannot control input files.

Comment: That's how it really goes @pLumo (inputs are controlled by me),  thanks for heads up anyways.

Comment: `NF-=1` can also be written `NF--` however note that not all `awk` implementations rebuild `$0` upon modifying `NF`. With some, including the original awk implementation, you'd need to add a `$1=$1` (with a difference in behaviour if the input doesn't contain `_` characters).

Answer (score 6):

To [not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), you can use a simple `loop` and `shell` syntax:

```bsh
for f in *; do echo "${f%_*}"; done
```

if you need to work further with that list (and you have a shell that  is capable of using arrays), you can add the items to an array:

```bsh
tokens=()
for f in *; do tokens=("${tokens[@]}" "${f%_*}"); done
echo "${tokens[@]}"
```

Or without the loop, directly declare the array:

```bsh
files=(*)
tokens=("${files[@]%_*}")
#or
for token in "${files[@]%_*}"; do echo "$token"; done
```

Comment: That's also another useful approach. Thanks for it.

Comment: `tokens+=("${f%_*}")` should work for appending to the array in the shells that support arrays. Or even `tokens=(*); tokens=("${tokens[@]%_*}")` for the whole deal.

Comment: ah yes, the last one is a good approach, I will add that.

Answer (score 2):

In the `zsh` shell:

```bsh
print -r -C1 -- *_*.sql(Ne['REPLY=${REPLY%_*}'])
```

This uses a glob qualifier that modifies the names that match the given globbing pattern `*_*.sql` by removing everything after and including the last underscore.  The actual substitution is made using a standard parameter substitution.

If you want to use the resulting strings to do something other than printing them, then use the globbing pattern, without the `print`, where that makes sense (e.g., in a `for` loop or as an argument to some other command). Don't put the `print` command from above in a command substitution!

Comment: See also `(){print -rC1 -- ${@%_*}} *_*.sql(N)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you need to do `ls -l`? 
Why not just do `ls`, or `printf '%s\n' *`,
to avoid generating the metadata (owner, size, date, etc.)
which you don’t want?

Then do

```
ls | sed 's/\(.*\)_.*/\1/'
```

This matches the longest possible string (the first `.*`)
that is followed by an `_`,
and then everything after it, and replaces it with only the first string.

Comment: Thanks for the info and your answer is close but it still gives the strings with an underscore. I need their right end trimmed.

Comment: Sorry; that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) { f=ARGV[i]; sub(/_[^_]*$/,"",f); print f }; delete ARGV}' *
abc_def_g
bbc
zz_b
```

That would work even if your file names contained newlines or any other characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'for dir(test => / .+ \.sql $ /) {.Str.subst(/  _ <-[_]>*? $ /).say};'
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages.

The solution above requires no call to `ls`, rather the `dir()` method in Raku can take a Regex-matcher, to look (for example) for files ending in `.sql`. Then those files can be examined individually, `subst`ituting with nothing (i.e. deleting) the two regex atom pattern `_` (underscore), and the bespoke character class `<-[_]>*?` which frugally-matches non-underscore characters (if any) occurring `$` at the end-of-string. File names ending in `.sql` but containing no underscores will be returned unchanged.

*Nota bene, the hope of such an approach--despite being posted on a Linux/Unix SE site--is that this code will run unchanged on WSL (see SO link below).*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973303/7270649
https://raku.org